# powershell move-item to a network folder doesn't work in windows 2012 task scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have the following piece of PowerShell code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem E:\Local_Files\Performance\*.txt -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne "" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}

Move-Item -Path E:\Local_Files\Performance\*.* -Destination E:\Local_Files\ -Force
```

It deletes empty rows for all files in a folder. Then, it moves any file on that folder to a second one. `Z:\` is a mapped network drive for a network folder. If I run the script in PowerShell, it works. When I schedule it in the Task Scheduler, it only works the first bit (the `Trim()` method).

I have setup the same username to run the job in both cases. If I use a local folder as a target for move-item, it works in the Task Scheduler as well.

Do you have any idea why it might not be working?

I am on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Many thanks,

Comment: Use the full UNC path instead of `Z:` (`\\bla`) ? Also, you do not show in your code that `Z:` is the destination for `Copy-Item`.

Comment: Thanks @sodawillow. The UNC path has worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapped drives are only mapped when a user logs on interactively. For a scheduled task, there is no interactive logon and therefore no mapped drives, so any attempt to use them will fail.

You can either:

- Map the drive letter in your script with `New-PSDrive`
- Use the UNC path to the share (preferred method).

Also bear in mind that the user account under which your task executes must have appropriate permissions on that UNC path/share.

Comment: Hi alroc, thanks for your tip. I has worked using the UNC path indeed. I'd say I tried that, but apparently not correctly. It has worked correctly this time by specifying the UNC path in singles quotes 'path'.
Thanks!